# Html body displaying different from the source

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, shopify, shopify-api

I want to add a product to my Shopify Account using [shopify-api](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2022-10/resources/product#post-products).
Just for the description part of the product, I have a problem and that's because my product description formatting gets different from [source website](https://www.lightinthebox.com/en/p/sports-gloves-bike-gloves-cycling-gloves-touch-gloves-windproof-waterproof-keep-warm-full-finger-gloves-lycra-spandex-cycling-bike-unisex_p6902601.html?category_id=799&prm=1.2.1.1) description.Thats my code to achieve this problem:

```
description = soup.find("div",class_="description-container")
description = description.find_all("div")
highlights = ''
selling_point = ''
specifications = ''
for desc in description:
    try:
        if desc["data-sort"]=="13":
            highlights = desc
        if desc["data-sort"]=="14":
            selling_point = desc
        if desc["data-sort"]=="15":
            specifications = desc
    except:
        continue
```

```
payload ={
    "product":
    {
      "title": "aaaa1",
      "price": price,
      "body_html": str(highlights)+str(selling_point)+str(specifications),
      "sku":sku,
      "images":original_images,
      "product_type": "Cycling",
      "tags":tags}}
```

But you should see the difference between my product and the source product, whats the issue? How to solve that?(the Highlights topic is working correctly so that not included in pictures):
**Source**:

[image]
**Mine:**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

```
description = soup.find("div",class_="description-container")
highlights = description.find("div", {"data-sort": 13})
selling_point = description.find("div", {"data-sort": 14})
specifications = description.find("div", {"data-sort": 15})

payload ={
    "product":
    {
      "title": "aaaa1",
      "price": 'price',
      "body_html": f'{highlights} {selling_point} {specifications}',
      "sku":'sku',
      "images":'original_images',
      "product_type": "Cycling",
      "tags": 'tags'
      }
}
```

And you can't have the exact style of `source`, for that you need to create appropriate CSS for it.

Comment: Is it possible with shopify api to do that? Would you please add the CSS part too?

Comment: It's almost impossible to add the CSS part when you do the scraping. You need to write the custom CSS along with this scraped HTML.

Comment: I know, suppose the scraping part finished and I should add css .My boss wanted mo to the description br as same as the source. What to do?I need your help

Comment: @etel876 Just take a sample scrapped HTML body and style it with CSS and add it along with the result. You need to create a custom CSS and inject it along with the source, it might be in-line CSS or part of the HTML content (I am not an expert in HTML styling you can refer other sources as well regarding how you inject the CSS).